# Combine two associative arrays and retain the keys while performing an operation on duplicate keys in php

Tags: php, arrays

Yes, I know there are many similar questions but they do not give what I want. The arrays that I have look something like this.

```
Array 1: ( [count] => 1 [6] => 1 )
Array 2: ( [count] => 3 [6] => 1 [1] => 2)
```

Now when combining two arrays I need to add the value of duplicate keys. So it must look something like this.

```
New Array: ( [count] => 4 [6] => 2 [1] =>2 )
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what results you're getting. We're glad to help you sort out specific issues with your code, but we're not here to write it all for you (which would be needed to properly answer the question at this time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop your arrays and form new array with added values by keys:

```php
<?php

$data = [
    ['count' => 1, 6 => 1],
    ['count' => 3, 6 => 1, 1 => 2],
];

$newArray = [];

foreach ($data as $datum) {
    foreach ($datum as $key => $value) {
        // You can remove this code if you trust `count` value, now I recalculate it
        if ($key == 'count') {
            continue;
        }

        // < PHP7.4; if (!isset($newArray[$key])) $newArray[$key] = 0;
        $newArray[$key] ??= 0;
        $newArray[$key] += $value;
    }
}

// Recalculate new count for array
$newArray['count'] = array_sum($newArray);

var_dump($newArray);

/*
array(3) {
  [6]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  ["count"]=>
  int(4)
}
*/
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e127d1ba2015fb937a87ec8eeb6e5e9e3d67a93)

Comment: Please don't answer "gimme-code" type questions. It just reduces this site into a free coding service making people come back expecting the same in the future. The OP hasn't shown any effort at all in their question, it's basically just a requirement spec.